# Remove telephone as required

Tags: checkout, magento-1, validation

I need to remove the telephone as required in Magento for this I have followed some tutorial and make some changes first I just copy the **abstract.php** to local folder and comment the line

```
if (!Zend_Validate::is($this-&gt;getTelephone(), 'NotEmpty')) {
    $errors[] = $helper-&gt;__('Please enter the telephone number.');
}
```

after that i have removed all the validation class from **billing.php and shipping .php** and then in database `eav_attribute` table make required option to 0 and removed the validation rule from `customer_eav _attribute` table but after doing all these things i'm getting an alert box by saying

> Telephone is required value telephone length must be greater than 1
>   character
>   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the steps as given in the below link.

http://swarminglabs.com/magento-making-the-telephone-field-not-required-at-checkout/

Finally, you'll need to clear all of Magento's caches so that your changes take effect. In the Magento admin, got to System -> Cache Management, and clear all caches. Make sure to click the 'Flush Magento Cache' and 'Flush Cache Storage' buttons as well. This will force Magento to take note of your database changes.

Comment: This link is dead now.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to clear all of Magento's caches so that your changes take effect. In the Magento admin, got to **System -> Cache Management**, and clear all caches. Make sure to click the '`Flush Magento Cache`' and '`Flush Cache Storage`' buttons as well. This will force Magento to take note of your database changes.

Comment: i have already do this but no changes

Comment: Please check view source and confirm required validation is removed from billing.php and shipping.php

Comment: yes it is removed please check the site https://www.qnhealth.com/